# Консоль ничего не выводит

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio, циклы, случайные-числа

Написал программу для вывода рандомных чисел из диапазона от 1 до 4, но при исполнение программы, консоль ничего не выводит

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int a[4],i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        a[i] = 1 + rand() % 4;
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
                while (a[i] == a[j])
                {
                    a[i] = 1 + rand() % 4;
                }
        }
        cout << a[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы оптимист...

Когда в циклах совпадет `i==j` (а это произойдет при первом же входе в циклы, когда эти переменные обе равны 0), сколько времени будет выполняться ваш цикл `while (a[i] == a[j])`?

У вас просто бесконечный цикл, только и всего...

Comment: А как это можно исправить?

Comment: Просто случайным образом перемешать числа от 1 до 4 и вывести. Так проще всего.

Comment: мне просто нужно чтобы они были различны

Comment: Если вы перемешаете числа 1,2,3 и 4, от этого они не станут равны, честное слово....

Comment: Интересно, кому я дорогу перешел — второй день все ответы анонимно минусуют? :)